# How to remove two colliding ids from a cart in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to properly add and remove items to a cart in my program, but so far have managed to add items to the cart ok. However, it works only partially when items of different categories are put together.

These are how items are displayed in the "Services" JSON:

```
"id": "0",
"type": "service",
"name": "Washing",
"isFavorite": false
```

And this is how items can be found in the "times" JSON:

```
"id": "0",
"type": "time",
"day": "today",
"time": "09:40",
"isFavorite": false
```

My useState hook with the cartItems and the methods created to add and remove them from the cart:

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

function addToCart(newItem) { 
        setCartItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, newItem])
    }

    function removeFromCart(itemToRemove) { 
        setCartItems(prevItems => prevItems.filter(item => 
            item.id !== itemToRemove.id))
    }
```

How I am removing and adding items to the cart in the differente components for the Services and for the Times:

```
//Services
const isSelected = allServices[props.id].isFavorite ? 

    <i className="icon-selected" onClick={() => context.removeFromCart(props)}> &#9664; </i> 

    : hovered && <i className="icon-hover" onClick={() => context.addToCart(props)}> &#128946; </i> 

//Times
const isSelected = (id) =>  allTimes[id].isFavorite ? 

    <i className="icon-fix" onClick={() => context.removeFromCart(allTimes[id])}> &#9664; </i>

    : hovered && <i className="icon-fix" onClick={() => context.addToCart(allTimes[id])}> &#128946; </i>
```

I have tried changing my removeFromCart function to `item.id !== itemToRemove.id && item.type === type` so that the id isn't the only criteria but have had no success.

Comment: Can you perhaps use the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) library to make sure the id's are unique?

Comment: If the ID's for each category are unique could you concatenate the id with the category name? IE: `${item.id}-${item.type}` !== `${itemToRemove.id}-${itemToRemove.type}`

Comment: Thank you @Chad, that solved iT!

Comment: @kiabbott Sure thing! I'll add it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID's for each category are unique could you concatenate the id with the category name? IE:`${item.id}-${item.type} !== ${itemToRemove.id}-${itemToRemove.type}`

Answer (score 0):

I think your function works well, but the issue can be during the iteration because if you iterate all your elements with a specific key ( for example id ) React will not display it properly.